# how to know which encryption algorithm is used

Tags: encryption

I have an encrypted code and decrypted code how to know the algorithm?

```
encrypted code of "A" is "bc1M4j2I4u6VaLpUbAB8Y9kTHBs="
encrypted code of "B" is "rk8oHfWl0P88rWNx921cKbbZU+w="
encrypted code of "C" is "MglsLg7/M9hE7m1nVAes4YKJNX0="
```

I am making an application which must use that algorithm I have only encrypter software that creates the code but I don't know the algorithm.
How do I know the algorithm?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identifying an encryption algorithm is *too broad* and has no value for future readers ([ref](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277984/1816580)).

Comment: SHA-1 is a hashing algorithm and not an encryption algorithm. Encryption is keyed and reversible which SHA-1 is not.

Comment: Poster is fortunate folks here either recognized the sequences or tried a few algorithms to find a match.  It is a characteristic of all good hash algorithms and encryption algorithms that they must be as close to indistinguishable as possible from pure randomness.  As a consequence, they will necessarily also be indistinguishable from one another in general.  Of course, if a person recognizes the output of a hash or encryption function for a specific pre-image or plain text, then in that specific case the generality will not apply.  But in all other cases it does.

Comment: well, in this case the = at the end was a giveaway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [SHA1 base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash algorithm
See this Ruby code

```
require 'digest/sha1'
puts Digest::SHA1.base64digest 'A'
# bc1M4j2I4u6VaLpUbAB8Y9kTHBs=
```

Comment: can I do this in PHP?

Comment: SHA-1 is a hashing algorithm and not an encryption algorithm. Encryption is keyed and reversible which SHA-1 is not.

Comment: @Artjom, the wiki talks about a 'cryptographic hash function', but you are right and I'll adapt this

Comment: @Saqib, don't know since I don't code in PHP but I'm sure it can easily be googled

Comment: @SaqibAhmed - PHP has a function named [sha1()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), maybe...